# hibernate hsqldb identity column fails to insert new fields

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, hsqldb

I am using an HSQL database for testing a spring hibernate project and recently introduced an identity field.

The java class looks like (snippet):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyTable {

    @Column(name = "sequence_number")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long sequenceNumber;
```

}

My sql script to generate the table is given below (snippet):

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    "sequence_number" BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    PRIMARY KEY("sequence_number")
);
```

When I try to add values to the datebase the sql (via show_sql) is:

```sql
insert into my_table (sequence_number) values (default)
```

I get an exeption stack trace with as key indicators:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: SEQUENCE_NUMBER
```

My suspicion is that HSQLDB does not like the `default` SQL keyword and would like to see `null` instead. Is there anyway to get this behaviour through hibernate?

Otherwise, is there a way to get this code to work?

I am using hibernate 4.2.8 and HSQLDb 2.3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the quotes in the sql. This makes the column names case-sensitive in hsqldb. hibernate tries to find a name with ALL-CAPS.

Changing the ddl in:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    sequence_number BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    PRIMARY KEY(sequence_number) );
```

solved the issue.